# aria-labelledby and aria-hidden tags meaning

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am building a website using Bootstrap 3. I wanted to implement modals in my website. I made them with the help of the documentation.

Now, I have this code, which makes the modal window:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

And this code for the modal title:

```
 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Flexibilní mřížka</h4>
```

Of course there are several more rows of a code but what I would like to know the meaning of `aria-labbeledby` and `aria-hidden` attributes. I found some explanations but nothing in particular which would help me to understand.

Comment: **http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles** is your friend :)

Comment: see also [**What are these attibutes: aria-labelledby and aria-hidden**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18933084/1407478)

Comment: Well I have read all these, I am probably dumb, but I still dont understand the use of them. @davidkonrad

Comment: See also this-> **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute** `aria-labelledby` can be used by assistive tech such as a screen reader to tell the user what an element is - a description. `aria-hidden` instruct the same screen reader to ignore an element. Checkout for example this bootstap modal example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/pw3xztsL/**

Comment: So It basically is usable for blind people for example? @davidkonrad